# find curvature at depth map

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, depth

I want to find curvature at depth map
Look at the picture

[image]
[image]

This is example of curvature
Maybe if i represent image as function and take second derivative from it a can find curvatures. But i couldn't to implement it. (I tryed sobel operator from opencv)

Is there way out?

PS Sorry for my writing mistakes. English in not my native language.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a depth map, it is a point cloud (but I assume it is generated from one single depth map  z = f(x,y).

What curvature do you want to estimate? Mean, Gaussian, the whole 2nd fundamental form?
See, e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_surfaces) for definitions. Here's a [recent reference](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~olano/papers/theses/Griffin2010.pdf) on fast estimation methods: